# Formik - TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror, formik

I've pretty much just [copy pasted this code from here](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-checkbox-example-96miz?from-embed) :

```
function Checkbox(props) {
  return (
    <Field name={props.name}>
      {({ field, form }) => (
        <label>
          <input
            {...field}
            type="checkbox"
            checked={field.value.includes(props.value)}
            onChange={() => {
              const set = new Set(field.value);
              if (set.has(props.value)) {
                set.delete(props.value);
              } else {
                set.add(props.value);
              }
              field.onChange(field.name)(Array.from(set)); //the problem seems to lie here somewhere!
              form.setFieldTouched(field.name, true);
            }}
          />
          {props.value}
        </label>
      )}
    </Field>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ roles: [] }}
      onSubmit={values => alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2))}
    >
      {formik => (
        <div>
          Clicking checks affects `VALUES` and `ERRORS` but never `TOUCHED`...
          <div>
            <Checkbox name="roles" value="admin" />
            <Checkbox name="roles" value="customer" />
          </div>
          <br />
          VALUES:
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(formik.values, null, 2)}</pre>
          ERRORS:
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(formik.errors, null, 2)}</pre>
          TOUCHED:
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(formik.touched, null, 2)}</pre>
        </div>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
}
```

The Sandbox seems to be working, but whenever I check a checkbox locally, I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
(anonymous function)
node_modules/formik/dist/formik.esm.js:659
  656 |   dispatch({
  657 |     type: 'SET_ERRORS',
  658 |     payload: errors
> 659 |   });
  660 | }, []);
  661 | var setValues = useEventCallback(function (values) {
  662 |   dispatch({
```

Not sure what I've done wrong here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of field.onChange use setFieldValue helper function

```
field.onChange(field.name)(Array.from(set)); //the problem seems to lie here somewhere!
```

replace with:

```
form.setFieldValue(field.name,(Array.from(set)));
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/formik-checkbox-example-l9p1p?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 17):

If anyone stumbles across this with a basic from producing the above error, it could be because you missed adding `initialValues` to `Formik` component.

Just fix it by adding

```
<Formik initialValues={{}} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
```

This fixed it for me!

Comment: yes, adding initialValues back fixed it for me.

Comment: This does fix the problem, though the console generates a different warning: "Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen.".  I don't know if the form will continue to work as expected, but it seems like if you want the initial field values to all be blank, it's better to specify that explicitly. e.g. initialValues={{"field1": "", etc...}}

Answer (score 0):

There is some action issue in your react-redux so i suggest you to please check your action type i think you action type is not defined that's why it shows undefined and getting error.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue when i use form with `<FieldArray/>` component so i find the best solution.

**wrap up your form or formik components with formik provider**

```
<FormikProvider value={formik}> 
  <Formik/>
</FormikProvider>
```