# React Formik gives Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fullName') error

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik

I use formik react mui tech and this code block gives

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fullName')

```
 const formik = useFormik({
    initalValues: {
        fullName: "",
        email:"",
        phone:"",
        select:"",
        message:""
    },
    onSubmit: (values)=> {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(values))
    },
})


 <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
            <Grid container spacing={3}>
                
                <Grid item md={6} xs={12}>
                    <TextField fullWidth name='fullName' value={formik.values.fullName} onChange={formik.handleChange} id="fullName" label="Ad Soyad" variant="outlined" />
                </Grid>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formik - TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59878570/formik-typeerror-cannot-read-property-type-of-undefined)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misspelt "initialValues" as "initalValues" so Formik is not reading it.

Comment: Oh i didn't have breakfast that day thanks...